# $odata.error$message$lang when retrieving data from Azure Table via REST API

Tags: r, azure, rest

When connecting to an Azure Table via REST API I'm getting back the following error:

```
$odata.error
$odata.error$code
[1] "InvalidInput"

$odata.error$message
$odata.error$message$lang
[1] "en-US"

$odata.error$message$value
[1] "One of the request inputs is not valid.\nRequestId:7aab8714-0002-0049-342c-20a215000000\nTime:2022-02-12T16:24:21.6562955Z"
```

I cannot pinpoint what is causing it: in the parameters for the REST API there are no language settings and the cycle to retrieve the data goes through 5 times before throwing the error, so I can get some 4,400 records from the table.

These are the headers before it fails (connection parameters are not real):

```
-> GET /UsageRecords?NextPartitionKey=1!16!MjAyMS0xMi0wOA--&NextRowKey=KEY HTTP/1.1
-> Host: storageaccountb.table.core.windows.net
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.64.1 r-curl/4.3.2 httr/1.4.2
-> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
-> Authorization: SharedKey storageaccountbillb81c6:kezpv8r1KwiPNNx8WOtOJ7Bh0ixIeVoJyItu1XDpeII=
-> x-ms-date: Sat, 12 Feb 2022 16:24:12 GMT
-> x-ms-version: 2020-12-06
-> Content-type: text/xml
-> 
<- HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<- Cache-Control: no-cache
<- Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<- Content-Type: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;streaming=true;charset=utf-8
<- Server: Windows-Azure-Table/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
<- x-ms-request-id: 7aab86f2-0002-0049-1c2c-20a215000000
<- x-ms-version: 2020-12-06
<- X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
<- Date: Sat, 12 Feb 2022 16:24:20 GMT
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error message is related to an invalid input value. Please edit your question and include your code as well.

Comment: Hi, apologies... I looking for an error because the data wasn't sorted on the right time field. The script retrieves all the rows, it's just that during the last loop, the "next" parameters don't find the right information and it throws an error. I will try to find a way to exit the loop before the missing headers are checked against the server. Thanks for the hint though!